# Build LaTeX PDF on Jenkins/Hudson

Tags: ant, latex, hudson, jenkins

The team I work for manages a large collection of technical documentation which is written in LaTeX. Currently all the documentation we have is manually built by the editors and then checked into a version control system.

Is there a possibility to build the LaTeX files on jenkins/hudson?

Comment: Can you speak about how you write this documentation? Class files, format, etc.? Perhaps here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_talk:Limited_Atonement is a better place for the discussion.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you can build your LaTeX files from the command line, Jenkins can build it for you.
Just create a job with a "Execute shell" build step.

You've tagged this question with [ant], so if you're building your documentation using an Ant script, you can alternatively add an "Invoke Ant" build step which calls the appropriate target.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on which build system you're using you can also use plugins e.g. for Maven or Gradle. You can have a look at https://github.com/reallyinsane/mathan-latex-maven-plugin where you can find a maven and a gradle plugin. You can use them with none or less configuration.